# execute a command during every n-th iteration

Tags: bash

I would like to print "is OK" during every odd loop iteration(first, third, fifth, etc) and print "is not OK" during every even loop iteration(second, fourth, sixth, etc). I'm able to accomplish this with:

```
$ for (( i=0,j=24,k=48; i<=200; i=i+48,j=j+48,k=k+48 )); do printf '%s\n%s\n' ""$i" to "$j" is OK" ""$j" to "$k" is not OK"; done
0 to 24 is OK
24 to 48 is not OK
48 to 72 is OK
72 to 96 is not OK
96 to 120 is OK
120 to 144 is not OK
144 to 168 is OK
168 to 192 is not OK
192 to 216 is OK
216 to 240 is not OK
$
```

However, is there a more elegant solution to accomplish the same?

Comment: How do 24, 48, 72, ... figure in both OK and not OK?

Comment: To clarify is "0 to 24" your loop iteration 1, "24 to 48" is iteration 2, etc.?

Comment: Not clear why you're running loop from 24 to 200 in the increments of 24.

Comment: @MicahSmith Exactly. Sorry for being bit unclear.

Comment: @anubhava It's just a random example to demonstrate the output I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator `%` for that:

```
for (( i=0; i<200; i+=24 )); do
  echo -n "$i to $((i+24)) is "
  ((i % 48 != 0)) && echo -n "not "
  echo OK
done
```

Comment: "i / 24 % 2 != 0" ?? I think "i % 48 != 0" does the same.

Comment: @Vouze Don't know what I was thinking. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

This code will output the same results as yours:

```
for (( i=0; i<=216; i+=24 )); do
    let j=i+24
    let v=(i/24)%2                           #calculate the iteration number
    if [ "$v" -eq 0 ]; then                  #if [ the iteration number is even ]
            printf ""$i" to "$j" is OK\n"
    else
            printf ""$i" to "$j" is not OK\n"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you regard this as more elegant but it's a bit shorter and makes your `for` loop a bit cleaner:

```
$ for i in {0..9}; do 
    s="$((i*24)) to $(((i+1)*24)) is"
    ((i%2)) && s+=" not"
    echo "$s OK"
done
```

or without using a variable `s`:

```
$ for i in {0..9}; do 
    echo "$((i*24)) to $(((i+1)*24)) is" $(((i%2)) && echo " not") "OK"
done
```

`((i%2))` will evaluate to 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd numbers, so it can be used to conditionally add "not" every other iteration. You can also use `((i&1))` to do a bitwise AND operation, which will do the same thing in this case.

Obviously, if *elegance* is what you want, you might prefer to use Perl:

```
perl -E 'say $_*24," to ",($_+1)*24," is"," not"x($_%2)," OK" for 0..9'
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "elegant" ?

```
t=('' 'not ')
for ((i=0, c=0; i<=200; i+=24, c=1-c))
do echo "\"$i\" to \"$((i+24))\" is ${t[c]}OK\n"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a range for the iteration:

```
 for i in {0..4}; do
   printf '%s\n%s\n' ""$((i* 48))" to "$((i*48+24))" is OK" ""$((i*48+24))" to "$((i*48+48))" is not OK";
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use functions to separate the logic, e.g.:

```
oenum=0
isodd() {
    let oenum++
    (( $oenum % 2 )) && return 0 || return 1
}

do_odd_thing() {
    echo "ODD ($oenum) item: $@"
}

do_even_thing() {
    echo "EVEN($oenum) item: $@"
}

#any loop - e.g. here the find command
while  read -r something
do
    isodd && do_odd_thing "$something" || do_even_thing "$something"
done < <(find /bin -type f -print)
```

The above produces (at least on my comp):

```
ODD (1) item: /bin/[
EVEN(2) item: /bin/bash
ODD (3) item: /bin/cat
...
ODD (35) item: /bin/unlink
EVEN(36) item: /bin/wait4path
ODD (37) item: /bin/zsh
```